# Open dropdown options while loading the page using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angularstrap selectbox to render the values. But i need to automatically open(auto focus) the dropdown while clicking on the tab.(dropdown is the first field)

I tried using tabindex="1" but no luck.

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-default" 
        data-ng-model="searchtype" 
        data-html="1" 
        ng-options="searchvalue as searchvalue for searchvalue in searchon" 
        placeholder="{{'myactivityqueue.form.searchon.placeholder' | translate}}"  
        bs-select tabindex="1">
  Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: if you could create a jsfiddle/plunkr it'll be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution,

```
.directive('focusOn',function($timeout) {

        return {

        restrict : 'A',

        link : function($scope,$element,$attr) {

        $scope.$watch($attr.focusOn,function(_focusVal) {

        $timeout(function() {       
        _focusVal ? $element.focus() :  
        $element.blur();

        });

        });

        }

        }

        });
```

And in the template file,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default searchType" data-ng-model="searchtype" data-html="1" ng-options="searchvalue as searchvalue for searchvalue in searchon" placeholder="{{'myactivityqueue.form.searchon.placeholder' | translate}}"  bs-select tabindex="1" focus-on="focusInput">
                      Action <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
```

and in the controller,

```
            //setting boolean value for autofocus dropdown 
            $scope.focusInput = true;
```